# Python - ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, function

I'm having an issue with this error - I've check a few articles around the use of operators and .all(),.any() etc but can't seem to get it to work with my example.  My code is below if you can help please?

```
def run_backtest(self):
#run strategy backtest - position multiplied by each returns record



    data= self.results.copy()
    if data[(data["position"] == 0) & (data["position"].shift(1) == 1)]:
        
        data["position2"] = 1
    else:
        data["position2"] = -1

    data["strategy"]= data["position"].shift(1)*data["returns"]
    data["trades"] = data.position.diff().fillna(0).abs() #used to record number of trades taken
    data.strategy = data.strategy + data.trades * self.tc #used to calculate the trade cost
    
    self.results = data
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.  Just had to use .any() at the end of my comparison logic :)

Comment: ah, doesn't quite work.  Now I've added the .any(), it just puts a 1 in the position2 field for all records.  Still need some help here pls :)